# Ionic 3 BLE update device list array

Tags: angular, ionic3, bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins

I'm using Ionic 3 and the BLE module. I need to update my `deviceList` array when a device stops advertising (remove it from the array). We have a physical button that turns off after you hold the button down for a period of time but `deviceList` does not remove the device from `deviceList`

Basically:

```
deviceList = [];

scanForDevices(){
  console.log("scan for devices");
  this.ble.startScan([]).subscribe(device => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
        this.deviceList.push(device);
    });
 this.connect(device);
}
```

Any help would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

BLE don't notify you when it stop advertising, so you can't aware when BLE device stop. However for an acceptable result, you can determine a BLE device stop advertising when a long time to see it in scan results.

Ionic BLE have an option when you scan BLE

```
{ reportDuplicates: true }
```

- You can use this option and update the time you see a device into device list.
- run a job to check time of all device in list, if it is too old => manual remove it from your list